# Perl: removing acronym hyphens within a longer string

Tags: regex, perl

I have a block of text that has acronyms. The acronyms are all written with hyphens, which I want to remove, most likely with s/. The trick is the acronyms can be variable letters long A-B, A-B-C, A-B-C-D, A-B-C-D-E.

So if I have a string, "welcome to the U-S-A competition between B-A and R-C-T-C" and I want to convert it to "welcome to the USA competition between BA and RCTC", how would I do this? Words like "well-coached" should not be affected.

So far, I have three s/ that first replace all four-letter acronyms, then three, then two. Is there a better way to do this with one single s/ expression?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution:

```
s/-(?=\p{Lu}\b)//g
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zO7bI6/1)

Which means: find a dash followed by an uppercase letter which is a word boundary. Replace with an empty string.

And here's a smiley-friendly version with the same check on the left of the dash:

```
s/(?<=\b\p{Lu})-(?=\p{Lu}\b)//g
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zO7bI6/2)

Comment: please note, that your regex also cuts the nose of the `:-D` smiley :D

Comment: @h3n you're totally right, I've updated the answer, thanks! :-D

Answer (score 0):

You also can use this

```
s/(?<=[A-Z])-(?=[A-Z])//g
```

It's easily done by lookaround

**Explanation**

`(?<=[A-Z])`: look behind to find any single capital letter,

`-`: match any minus sign,

`(?=[A-Z])`: look ahead to find any single capital letter.

Then finally, replace `-` by zero-width character.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:

```
$sentence =~ s/([A-Z])\-/$1/g;
```

It seems to work as intended (aside from missing lower-case acronyms). Is there an obvious problem in this that I'm missing? It feels like it should be more detailed like the answers provided. Thanks!